# Ruby implementation of Secret Santa

Tags: ruby

The problem is stated as follows:
There is a list of persons, each having first name and last name. People having same last name belong to same family. 
Aim is to chose a secret santa for each person such that the secret santa is ofcourse not the same person, nor does she belong to the same family.
I've taken liberty of assigning a santa from same family if there is no other choice.

I have following code to achieve this and am passing my tests - however I'm not very confident if this code produces correct results in all cases.

In case the algorithm is not correct I'll appreciate if someone can explain why this algorithm fails, also review of code will be quite helpful.

The main method in code is assign_angels, and I have tried to return self from most of my methods following the [East Oriented Code](http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2014/12/23/enforcing-encapsulation-with-east-oriented-code/)

This problem is taken from [Ruby Quiz: Secret Santa](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz2.html)

I'm using the equalizer module for equality checking [Equalizer](https://github.com/dkubb/equalizer)

```
require 'set'
require 'equalizer'

class People

  include Equalizer.new(:people)

  def initialize personList = []
    @people = Array(personList).to_set
  end

  def add person
    @people.add person
    self
  end

  def assign_angels
    @people.each do |person|
      eligible_santas
        .preferably_of_different_family(person)
        .assign_angel_to_one(person)
    end
    self
  end

  def to_s
     @people.map { |person| person.to_s }
  end

  protected

  def sample
    @people.to_a.sample || NilPerson.new
  end

  def size
    @people.size
  end

  def assign_angel_to_one person
    sample.assign_angel person
    self
  end

  def eligible_santas
    People.new @people.select { |person| person.angel == nil }
  end

  def preferably_of_different_family person_a
    different_family = people_of_different_family person_a
    if different_family.size == 0
      same_family = people_of_same_family person_a
      if(same_family.size == 0)
        return People.new NilPerson.new
      end
      return same_family
    end
    return different_family
  end

  def people_of_different_family person_a
    People.new @people.select { |person| person unless person.is_family? person_a }
  end

  def people_of_same_family person_a
    People.new @people.select { |person| person unless person == person_a }
  end

  attr_reader :people
end
```

Comment: Yep I've been a good secret santa myself :D And have gotten amazing secret santa's too

Comment: Your code looks beautifully designed. I can't think of something wrong unless we try and take it to a multithreaded environment...

Comment: Do you have the whole app? I'd love to look at it!